# UIImagePickerController 720p 1080p recording size issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to record video at 720p and 1080p using uiimagepickercontroller. Both videos have exact 1 min duration but strangely 720p video has size of 330MB while 1080p video has size approx. 130MB. I checked that and it was bit rate issue. 720p is at 40Mbit/s & 1080p is at 17Mbit/s.

AVFoundation is the only solution ? Please mention if there's any solution for it using UIImagePickerController

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are picking `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeIFrame1280x720` which produces a video file with the native full-bandwidth quality video, with a "soft setting" resolution of 1280x720. In other words you could potentially change the resolution higher after the fact.

What you want to do is take the video file and run it through `AVAssetExportSession` with the preset `AVAssetExportPreset1280x720`. This will product a smaller video file at 1280x720 by throwing away some of the bandwidth and extra quality.